# Subtracting 12 when the sum of two variables is greater or equal to 12

Tags: python, set, theory, music-notation

I come from a musical background, so I was interested in implementing music set theory into a Python script.

Basically the variables of musical notes are assigned to numbers (C = 0, C sharp = 1 etc.). However music set theory only works up to the number 11, since B = 11 and the next C would be = 0 again.

I've assigned some variables already, they look like this.

```
# pitch classes
Bs = C = 0
Cs = Db = 1
D = 2
Ds = Eb = 3
E = Fb = 4
F = Es = 5
Fs = Gb = 6
G = 7
Gs = Ab = 8
A = 9
As = Bb = 10
B = Cb = 11

# intervals
m2 = 1 
mj2 = 2 
m3 = 3 
mj3 = 4
P4 = 5 
T = 6
P5 = 7
m6 = 8
mj6 = 9
m7 = 10
mj7 = 11
```

I want to be able to add notes and intervals together, for instance B plus a perfect 5. This would normally be 11 + 7 = 18, but I want it to equal 6 (since 6 = F sharp, and B and F sharp are a perfect 5th apart).

I think I need something like this, but I have no idea how to implement it.

```
if answer >= 12:
    answer - 12
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Is there a better way of going about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), `%` which does exactly this (see also [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)):

```
print((11 + 7) % 12)
```

or more generally:

```
def add_wrap_overflow(x,y):
    return (x+y) % 12
```

Comment: Haha this seems so obvious now, thanks so much. Anyway I can write something up so I don't have to type 'print((x + z) %12)' for every operation?

Comment: I don't quite understand. You can define a function, e.g. `module_add(x,y)` which does this for you, but you'd have to call this function every time - see updated answer

Comment: Okay I'll probably a little out of my depth, I don't quite understand either. Your first answer is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is almost correct; however, `answer - 12` is just an expression, i.e. it evaluates to the value `answer - 12` without having any additional effect.

You need to make a statement that assigns that value to some variable (in this case, the same one):

`answer = answer - 12`.

Python offers a short way of writing this (though you should avoid it as it might be confusing to beginners):

`answer -= 12`.

However in your case, the modulo operator may be more useful:

`answer = answer % 12`
or
`answer %= 12`

In short, the modulo operator subtracts or adds 12 *until* answer is in `range(0, 12)` (one of the numbers from 0 to 11).

Answer (score 0):

I would correct your code as

```
if (answer >= 12):
    answer = answer - 12
```

Comment: why the extra braces?